# Updating TextView on keyDown?

Tags: java, android, events, textview, keylistener

I am trying to update a TextView which will show the system volume. I have managed to capture the current system volume and display it, but it doesn't update when the volume is turned up/down (obviously).

I know there is an easy solution somewhere I just cant think! onKeyListeners?

I am now using this but it doesnt work:

```
TextView sysVol = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.systemVolume);        
    sysVol.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {                           
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
              if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {

                //system volume
                int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                int i = curVolume * 4;  
                String aString = Integer.toString(i);   

                TextView sysVol = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.systemVolume);
                sysVol.setText(aString);

                return true;
            }
                return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the pseudo approach would be the following scenario:

```
1) Attach a listener to the view
2) Filter the different events in the callback
3) Update the TextView upon the (event==volume_up OR event==volume_down)
```

Basically, you'd want to implement the `View.onKey()`-method for this to be a minor bump in the road, instead of the current roadblock-state.

Summary: Add the following snippet to your code (some modification needed)

```
public YourClassHere extends SomethingCool implements OnKeyListener /*<-- important part*/
{
    public boolean onKey(View v) {
      // do something when the selected button is pushed
      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got some code above which looks like what I need but isnt work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the textview is not refreshing after you have changed the text. Try putting `sysVol.requestLayout()` after you changed the text to refresh the textview. Also, I don't think you are suppose to put `return false` after the closing bracket of the onKey() method.

Comment: I was hopeful but it didn't work. It needs the return false if the key isnt vol up or down

Comment: What if you make a call to `invalidate()`? It's supposed to force a redraw of elements. `sysVol.invalidate()` would be the way to try it out.